# Where should I setup my algorithm before calling its method in a Driver?

Tags: java

```
class AlgosPart2
 {
  private double f2c;
  private double farenheit;

  public void f2c(double farenheit)
  {
   double celcius = (farenheit - 32) * 5/9;
   System.out.printf("F2C: %.2f%n", celcius);
   this.f2c = f2c;
  }
   public double getf2c()
  {
    return f2c;
  }
}
```

Im having a bit of trouble figuring out where to place the formula for converting farenheit to celcius. Did I place it in the wrong spot? Because the Driver is still not detecting the method when I call it.
Driver:

```
 public class Driver {
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    AlgosPart2 ap2 = new AlgosPart2();
    double x1 = getf2c(20);
  }
 }
```

The twenty is suppose to represent the farenheit, but the error occurs here. Not too sure where i went wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius in one method `f2c(...)` and then use the getter of `f2c`. Change the code to as follows :

```
class AlgosPart2 {
    private double f2c;

    public void f2c(double farenheit) {
        this.f2c = (farenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }

    public double getf2c() {
        return f2c;
    }
}
```

And then call it as follows :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AlgosPart2 ap2 = new AlgosPart2();
    ap2.f2c(20);
    System.out.println(ap2.getf2c());
}
```

Here we call the method `f2c` using the object `ap2` and then using the getter we can access the value of f2c previously assigned.

Answer (score 0):

call it like below

```
 AlgosPart2 ap2 = new AlgosPart2();
 double x1 = ap2.f2c(20);
```

change this method like this

```
public double f2c(double farenheit)
  {
   double celcius = (farenheit - 32) * 5/9;
   System.out.printf("F2C: %.2f%n", celcius);
   return celcius;
  }
```

Comment: @wick3djava nice to hear it. If it helps for u please upvote and accept.